# norm and projections on inner product space

Tags: abstract-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products, projection, dimension-theory-algebra

How do I show that if $\Vert Px-Qx \Vert <\Vert x \Vert$ for any $x\in V$ not $0$, then $\dim\left(M\right)=\dim\left(N\right)$.

$V$ is an inner product space and $M, N$ are sub-spaces of $V$.$P$ is a projection on $N$ and $Q$ is a projection on $M$.

I was given a clue, which says that I need to show that the projections $P|_N$ and $Q|_M$ are injective. (or maybe it is $P|_M$ and $Q|_N$, I'm not sure).

Anyway I don't understand how to approach to this question.

Comment: Do $P, Q$ may be non orthogonal projections?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Indeed, $P|_M$ must be injective. Otherwise, there is an $x \in M$ for which $Px = 0$, which would imply that $\|Px - Qx\| = \|0 - x\| = \|x\|$.

Comment: so if $P|_M$ injective and $Q|_N$ injective, as a result dimM = dimN ?

Comment: @Ilya.K. Yes. In particular, $P|_M$ being injective implies that $\dim(M) \leq \dim(N)$.